# How do i get the text of a dynamically created label , when i click from anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In my JSP page ,i want to dynamically create a label, which is inside a achor tag. when i clik another anchor tag , i want to get corresponding label text using javascript or jquery.

This is my JSP page code.

```
<body>
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < sam.groupName.length; i++) {

            out.print("<a href='#'>");
            out.print("<img src='twoMen.jpg'/>");
            out.print("<label for='groupsId' id='labelId"+i+"'>"+ sam.groupName[i] + "</label>");
            out.print("</a>");

            out.print("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='validation(this,"+i+");'>Edit</a>");

        }
    %>
</body>
```

Javascript code:

```
function validation(anchor,i) {
        alert("Label value="+????);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you put a label element inside an anchor element? Labels already have a behaviour on click (setting the focus to the associated form control, and in the case of a checkbox or radio button actually checking/unchecking it), so putting a label inside an element that has its own click behaviour seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
function validation(anchor,i) {
    var value = $("#labelId"+i).text();
    alert("Label value= "+ value);
}
```

Just use the ID of the label you have, then get the text from it.

`.text()` will return to you the TEXT that is in the tag. Not if that text is contained within another nested tag. If that is the case, use `.html()` or specify your jQuery selector.

**UPDATE**

I also thought of another solution, this one will be simpler I think:

```
<body>
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < sam.groupName.length; i++) {

        out.print("<a href='#'>");
        out.print("<img src='twoMen.jpg'/>");
        out.print("<label for='groupsId' id='labelId"+i+"'>"+ sam.groupName[i] + "</label>");
        out.print("</a>");

        out.print("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='validation(this,'"+sam.groupName[i]+"');'>Edit</a>");

    }
    %>
</body>
```

then you can use the validation function as follows:

```
function validation(anchor,value) {
    alert("Label value="+ value);
}
```

This does the same, but it passes the value you need instead of the index pointing to the value you need. This works UNLESS you need the i index for anything else later on.

Answer (score 0):

Give some class to anchor's say class1, and use live method of jquery as,

```
$(".class1").live("click",function(){
alert(this.html())
});
```

Comment: wouldn't help the issue OP is having. He's trying to retrieve the text from a label when a link is clicked. That link already fires towards the `validation(achor, i)` function.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases the best thing is look at how the final code is rendered. 
However, you can take it from the ID:

```
var myLabelId = 'labelId'+i;
var myLabel =   document.getElementById(myLabelId);
var myLabelValue = myLabel.innerText;
```

Comment: The label's ID is not 'labelId'. The index (i) is also added. See my answer :)